# Introspect whether a process created with `start_process` is still running and when it exits

Tags: process

I'm using [`start-process`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Asynchronous-Processes.html) to run a process upon certain events picked up with hooks

```
(start-process "foo" "*Foo*" foo-command foo-args)
```

I would like to do 2 things with this.

- Prevent the process from being started if it's already running
- Print a message to `*Messages*` when the process is complete

How can I do this please?

Comment: Please do not post the same question here and to StackOverflow. Choose one. Please delete one of these posts. Thx.

Comment: Have a look at `set-process-sentinel` to designate a function that generates a message when finished.  See also `get-process` and related functions:  https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Process-Information.html  This thread has a few examples:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24548536/penetrating-the-set-process-sentinel-hierarchy-with-let-bound-variables  Google `set-process-sentinel`, `start-process`, `process-filter` for additional examples.

Comment: @lawlist perhaps you could convert that to an answer, because process sentinels are the correct approach, and there isn't currently an Answer which explains that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see if a named process is currently running, you could use the `process-status` function. It will return `nil` if the named process is not running ...

```
process-status is a built-in function in `C source code'.

(process-status PROCESS)

Return the status of PROCESS.
The returned value is one of the following symbols:
run  -- for a process that is running.
stop -- for a process stopped but continuable.
exit -- for a process that has exited.
signal -- for a process that has got a fatal signal.
open -- for a network stream connection that is open.
listen -- for a network stream server that is listening.
closed -- for a network stream connection that is closed.
connect -- when waiting for a non-blocking connection to complete.
failed -- when a non-blocking connection has failed.
nil -- if arg is a process name and no such process exists.
PROCESS may be a process, a buffer, the name of a process, or
nil, indicating the current buffer's process.
```

And as stated here, a process sentinel is a way for code to be invoked (such as displaying a message) when the process ends.

Answer (score 0):

For your first question, you could iterate over the `process-list` and only run your command if the process is not found, eg.

```
(defun process-running-p (name)
  (cl-loop for proc in (process-list)
     if (and (string= name (process-name proc))
             (process-live-p proc))
     return t))

;; ignore if running and live
(unless (process-running-p "foo")
  ...)
```

Comment: See also the following related example that deals with similar process names due to subsequent calls before a prior process has finished; e.g., `preview`; `preview<1>`; `preview<2>`; etc.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/20023781/2112489